# Custom content in auto generated menu

Tags: nodes, routes

I have been working on a website that contains a main dropdown menu generated by Drupal (7.28). Is there any way I can add a link to it between the other links that shows content generated by me in the dropdown? So instead of: fetch pages, fetch something else (defined by me).

Thanks in advance =]

Answer (score 0):

Every module on your site can be found in the list on /admin/structure/menu.
just click 'list links' and then 'add link' to add a link to a menu.

Comment: Does this also enable me to generate my own content in the dropdown using PHP?